# batch find and replace

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

this is my problem:
on a Windows 2003 server I've a folder (c:\test), and every day an application put 3 new files on it.

1° file: 
31201610181207000100000000630001
31201610181213000100000000440001
31201610181227000100000000630001
....

2° file:
31201610181214000100000000380002
31201610181234000100000009830002
31201610181344000100000000380002
...

3° file:
31201610181826000100000000580003
31201610190722000100000000580003
31201610191801000100000000580003
...

My goal is to replace ONLY the last 4 characters on each file with a .bat or .vbs script 
 (0001 --> 0031)
 (0002 --> 0032)
 (0003 --> 0033)
.

I've done a .vbs file who works, but it search on all string and not on the last 4 characters.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objFSO, strFolder, objFolder, objFile
Dim strOldValue1, strNewValue1, strNewValue2, strOldValue2, strNewValue3,      
strOldValue3, objRead, strContents, objWrite
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strFolder = "c:\test"
strOldValue1 = "0001"
strNewValue1 = "0031"
strOldValue2 = "0002"
strNewValue2 = "0032"
strOldValue3 = "0003"
strNewValue3 = "0033"



' I take the folder
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)


' I count the file on the folder
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
' Read file with textstream object.
Set objRead = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, ForReading)
' Trap error if file is empty or cannot read.
On Error Resume Next
strContents = objRead.readall
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
    On Error GoTo 0
    Wscript.Echo "Cannot read: " & objFile.Path
    strContents = ""
End If
On Error GoTo 0
objRead.Close


' check what's is inside the folder


If (InStr(strContents, strOldValue1) > 0) Then

    strContents = Replace(strContents, strOldValue1, strNewValue1)
    Set objWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, ForWriting)
    objWrite.Write strContents
    objWrite.Close
End If


If (InStr(strContents, strOldValue2) > 0) Then

    strContents = Replace(strContents, strOldValue2, strNewValue2)
    Set objWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, ForWriting)
    objWrite.Write strContents
    objWrite.Close
End If


If (InStr(strContents, strOldValue3) > 0) Then

    strContents = Replace(strContents, strOldValue3, strNewValue3)
    Set objWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, ForWriting)
    objWrite.Write strContents
    objWrite.Close
End If

next
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Is the last part always on of these: `0001`, `0002`, `0003`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044)

```
for %%F in (c:\test\*) do call jrepl "000(?=[123]$)" "003" /f "%%F" /o -
```

The above looks at the end of each line for "000" before a "1", "2", or "3", and substitutes "003" for the "000".

JREPL is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - No 3rd party exe file required.

Comment: It's very compact! listen, if I want to change the line in that way: when I found "1" I change the "second" character of the string with "1", when I find  the "2" I change the "second" character with "2" etc... Is that possible?

Comment: @Matteo - Sure - you should study regular expressions; there are lots of tutorials online. You also should study the JREPL documentation - it is a powerful utility. I'm not sure how to interpret your request, but if you want 0001 to become 0131, and 0002 to become 0232, etc. then change the jrepl call to `call jrepl "000([123])$" "0$13$1" /f "%%F" /o -`

Comment: Thanks for the answer dbenham ! unfortunately is wrong because, what I mean is: original line :  31201610181207000100000000630001 --> modified line 31201610181207000100000000630001 (in this case nothing will be changed because the first 2 characters are already set correctly), second case original line: 31201610181207000100000000630002 modified line 32201610181207000100000000630002 (as you can see the second charater is changed in 2) original line: 31201610181207000100000000630003, modified line: 33201610181207000100000000630003 (as you can see the second charater is changed in 3)

Comment: @Matteo - Ummm, No. My answer does exactly as you requested in the actual original question. What you request in your comment is totally different then what you request in the original question. Does my answer do what you want - I suppose not. Does it answer your original question - Yes. This is supposed to be a programmers Q&A site, so you should be able to take what you learn and develop your own solutions. See if you can study regular expressions and adapt a solution. If you cannot, then ask a new question.

Comment: you're right, I've much to learn about regular expression, and of course your answer is right..... I've used the comment section in the wrong way.... I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short batch script, which immediately modifies all files `C:\test\*.*` accordingly:

```dos
for %%F in ("C:\test\*.*") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%L in ('type "%%~F" ^& ^> "%%~F" rem/') do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "LEFT=!LINE:~,-4!"
        set "RIGHT=!LINE:~-4!"
        if "!RIGHT!"=="0001" set "RIGHT=0031"
        if "!RIGHT!"=="0002" set "RIGHT=0032"
        if "!RIGHT!"=="0003" set "RIGHT=0033"
        >> "%%~F" echo(!LEFT!!RIGHT!
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!!!! it works!!

Also, if you're interested I've found how the make my script work:
I've to add the **& VBCrlf** to the variable, in this way the script will search for the value + the new line.

```
strOldValue1 = "0001" & VBCrlf
strNewValue1 = "0031" & VBCrlf
strOldValue2 = "0002" & VBCrlf
strNewValue2 = "0032" & VBCrlf
strOldValue3 = "0003" & VBCrlf
strNewValue3 = "0033" & VBCrlf
```